# Trying to write a solution to re-order an array without using sort()

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, while-loop

I feel like I'm close but not quite sure why my while loop stops executing, I want it to run/ increase the counter then the conditions are true, then when it runs into numbers out of order, swap them, then decrease the counter, then run the while loop again until all the numbers are in order. So like it slides the number that's out of order backwards until it's higher than the number before it but lower than then number after it. If that makes sense.Probably an easy one for most of you but I'm just new to python. Here is my code so far;

```
arr = [7, 14, 21, 32, 17, 48, 69, 78, 72]
count = 0

while (count < len(arr) - 1) and (arr[count] < arr[count+1]):
    count += 1
    if (arr[count] > arr[count+1]):
        arr[count], arr[count+1]  = arr[count+1], arr[count]
        count -= 1
    continue

print(count)

print(arr)
```

below my code with some pseudocode to make it clearer.

```
# list of numbers out of order

arr = [7, 14, 21, 32, 17, 48, 69, 78, 72]

# first position in index

count = 0

# loop to check first if value of index position is less than length of array -1 (9-1 = 8) 
# or if value of index position is less than index position + 1 (next index position)

while (count < len(arr) - 1) and (arr[count] < arr[count+1]):
# if true loop should continue + 1 on the next index
    count += 1
# if the value of number in the current index position is greater than the next number it swaps them.
    if (arr[count] > arr[count+1]):
        arr[count], arr[count+1]  = arr[count+1], arr[count]
        count -= 1
    continue

print(count)
    
        
print(arr)
```

I've tried various different things, I think I'm just stuck on how while loops actually work and I need to get the loop to run again after it hits it's first false statement.

Comment: Actually, I just realised the question is not to put the list in order, but to find the first 2 numbers out of order and swap them. Now I'm really lost.

Answer (score 0):

This would work in the way that is required in the question:

- finds the first two numbers that are out of order.
- switched those numbers only and exit.

```py
arr = [7, 14, 21, 32, 17, 48, 69, 78, 72]


for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    if i == len(arr) -1:
        print('reached the end')
        break
    if v > arr[i+1]:
        print('out of order index', i, 'value:',v)
        # do the switch
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], v
        break


print(arr)
```

the result is this:

```
out of order index 3 value: 32
[7, 14, 21, 17, 32, 48, 69, 78, 72]
```

You could also achieve the same with a `while loop` so long as a `break` condition existed.

Comment: ok, thanks but I see the two out of order numbers in the array haven't been swapped yet; 

I actually, tinkering fixed my code to print the two numbers out; but still don't know how to swap them;
"""
arr = [7, 14, 21, 32, 17, 48, 69, 78, 72]
out_of_order = []
i = 0
while (i<len(arr) -2):
    i += 1
    if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]):
        print(arr[i+1])
    
# arr[i], arr[i+1]  = arr[i+1],7 arr[i]

print(arr)
"""
Do I need to extract the numbers that are out of order and store them in another list and then swap them and then put them back in?

Comment: @JimLister .   in the comments on the original question it says *" to find the first 2 numbers out of order and swap them"*.   Nevertheless, you can sort all by removing the second `break` statement in the code, which would then continue to the end.